# bulk update in a datatasbe query

Tags: mysql

I have an Issue where I am trying to Update a Bulk Update to replace the value of one column from anotehr column.

Here is the data that i am generating from the below query

```
 ID     CodeID  credit   Image      creator   
47774   5635    none    5635.jpg    Freshy
47790   5643    none    5643.jpg    Fresh
47792   5643    none    5643AB.jpg  Fresh
47793   5643    none    5643FF.jpg  Fresh
47795   5643    none    56431.jpg   Fresh
47796   5643    none    56434B.jpg  Fresh
```

The last Column {Creator} is coming from a Join which is below:

I want to fill the creator values in the credit column same to same, how can do it

```
select mp.id, codeid, credit, image, creator 
from mp inner join mm on mm.id = mp.codeid 
where credit = 'none'
```

Tried the Update like this

```
update mp SET credit = (select creator 
from mp inner join mm on mm.id = mp.modid 
where credit = 'none')
```

Eventually got an error:

```
[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'mods_pics_copy' for update in FROM clause
```

there might be some way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax

```
UPDATE mp
JOIN mm ON mm.id = mp.codeid AND credit = 'none'
SET mp.credit = mm.creator;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the SET:
Here you must put the column name, not condition

`update mp SET columnname where credit = somecondition`